# Aspectj not working with eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aspectj

I´m trying to use aspectJ with eclipse 4.4.0 (Luna). Y cannot find any ajdt plugin suitable for this version of eclipse.

Anyway i think aspectj should work, so I put the aspectj jars in the lib directory of my webApp, and create this Aspect class:

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {

    @Before("(execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void intercept(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.print("before");
    }

    @After("(execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.print("after");
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void logException(JoinPoint jp, Exception t) {
        System.out.print("throwing");
    }
}
```

But nothing is being logged. What i´m missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then try with Kepler if you want to use AJDT. `;-)`

BTW, have you compiled your aspect and Java classes with *ajc* (AspectJ compiler)? Or do you want to compile them with *javac*? In this case you need to weave the aspects during runtime (LTW, load-time weaving) and need the weaving agent (`-javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`) plus a corresponding configuration in `aop.xml`. After you will have told me what you want to do, I can update this answer with a concrete example.

---

**Update:** Okay, I tested your aspect. It contains a few syntax errors and other problems, e.g.

- In `@Before("(execution(* *.*(..))")` there the number parentheses do not match. Instead it should be `@Before("execution(* *.*(..))")`.
- The after-throwing annotation misses the exception binding. It should be `@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))", throwing = "t")`.

Now here is a fully testable stand-alone example:

**Driver application:**

```java
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        try {
            sayHello("world");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e); 
        }
    }

    public void sayHello(String recipient) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + recipient + "!"); 
        throw new RuntimeException("Oops!");
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {
    @Before("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void intercept(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println("before " + jp);
    }

    @After("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println("after " + jp);
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))", throwing = "t")
    public void logException(JoinPoint jp, Exception t) {
        System.out.println("throwing " + jp);
    }
}
```

**How to compile & run with *ajc*:**

Assuming that your source files are in a directory named `src` and you want the class files to end up in `bin`, this is how you compile:

```
ajc -sourceroots src -1.7 -d bin -cp aspectjrt.jar
```

Now run the application:

```
java -cp bin;aspectjrt.jar Application

before execution(void Application.main(String[]))
before execution(void Application.foo())
before execution(void Application.sayHello(String))
Hello world!
after execution(void Application.sayHello(String))
throwing execution(void Application.sayHello(String))
Caught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Oops!
after execution(void Application.foo())
after execution(void Application.main(String[]))
```

**How to compile with javac & run with LTW:**

You need to compile with debug symbols (`-g`):

```
javac -g -cp aspectjrt.jar -d bin src\*.java
```

Before you can run the program you need a LTW configuration under `bin\META-INF\aop.xml` (or `aop-ajc.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="LoggerAspect"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver>
        <include within="*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Now you can run the application using the weaving agent:

```
java -javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar -cp bin Application
```

The output is the same, but if you want to see more you can add other weaver options like

```xml
<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
```

This should yield the following output:

```
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.main(java.lang.String[]))' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:3) advised by before advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.main(java.lang.String[]))' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:3) advised by after advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.main(java.lang.String[]))' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:3) advised by afterThrowing advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.foo())' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:8) advised by before advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.foo())' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:8) advised by after advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.foo())' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:8) advised by afterThrowing advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.sayHello(java.lang.String))' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:16) advised by before advice from 'LoggerAspect'(LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.sayHello(java.lang.String))' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:16) advised by after advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@58644d46] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void Application.sayHello(java.lang.String))' in Type 'Application' (Application.java:16) advised by afterThrowing advice from 'LoggerAspect' (LoggerAspect.java)
before execution(void Application.main(String[]))
before execution(void Application.foo())
before execution(void Application.sayHello(String))
Hello world!
after execution(void Application.sayHello(String))
throwing execution(void Application.sayHello(String))
Caught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Oops!
after execution(void Application.foo())
after execution(void Application.main(String[]))
```

If you need even more, add the `-debug` option to the weaver options, too.

Comment: i´m just doing "run on server..." on eclipse, so i´think is doing a simple javac.

Comment: Have you ever used AspectJ before? I mean, how much do you know? Please elaborate, so I know where to start. And can you first test without the server, just on a plain Java SE program?

Comment: Okay, I have heavily updated the answer and added sample code plus CTW and LTW compilation and running instructions. I do not know anything about your application server, so you have to figure out the classpath issues there by yourself, if any.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. As you guess, i´m new with AspectJ, so i will try your example, and try to find my path. I´m using tomcat as application server. What acj is?

Comment: It is *ajc*, not *acj*, and I have explained it right at the beginning. Please read more carefully.

Answer (score 20):

If you have set up the [AspectJ Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) in your pom.xml, then to make that work in Luna, it seems you first need to add the following update site (menu Help, Install New Software):

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update/

From that site, install *AspectJ Development Tools*.

Once installed, you can also install the *Maven Integration for AJDT* through Preferences, Maven, Discovery, Open Catalog, and then selecting *AspectJ m2e Configurator*.

(Trying to do the last step before installing the tools, will throw a *Missing requirement: AspectJ Development Tools Core 2.1.3.* The same error is thrown when trying to install AspectJ things from the default Luna update sites.)

Comment: Thank you Arjan, you helped me. There is also step-by-step tutorial how to install AspectJ Development Tools into Eclipse. http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/7174/install-aspectj-development-tools-into-eclipse

Comment: I deploy on WebSphere - and I'm not sure, but I think it's important to run a full `maven clean build` from Eclipse in order to get it to recognize the maven plugin and then for the "publish" to server process to recognize aspectj. I also upgraded the aspectJ library and maven plugin to the latest versions from the website. Then it *finally* worked. So if these steps still aren't working for you, try those things.

Comment: anyone ever get the debugger to actually work? or is that something that is impossible?